# Function for multiple statements

Tags: r

I have the following code that I use to uniform the names into a dataframe (tb):

```
names(tb) = tolower(names(tb))
names(tb) = gsub("\\:", "", names(tb))
names(tb) = gsub("\\.", "_", names(tb))
names(tb) = gsub("\\-", "_", names(tb))
names(tb) = gsub("[[:space:]+]", "_", names(tb))
```

I need to apply those 5 strings to multiple dataframes, so I'd like to create a function for this. Can you help me please? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to build your own function? Have you tried the function clean_names() from the package janitor?

Comment: We could make it more simple with `chartr("[.- ]", "---", gsub(":", "", tolower(names(tb)))))`

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple, just pass your dataframe to the function, change the names and then return the changed dataframe.

```r
name_change <- function(tb) {

names(tb) = tolower(names(tb))
names(tb) = gsub("\\:", "", names(tb))
names(tb) = gsub("\\.", "_", names(tb))
names(tb) = gsub("\\-", "_", names(tb))
names(tb) = gsub("[[:space:]+]", "_", names(tb))
return tb

}
```

Comment: This is pretty hard-coded and might be less efficient.

Comment: @NelsonGon it's not hardcoded at all? It takes the names of a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

It can be simplified in a function with

```
f1 <- function(v1) {
     gsub("[. -]+", "_", gsub(":", "", tolower(v1)))
  }
```

or using `chartr`

```
f2 <- function(v1) {
    chartr(". -", "___", gsub(":", "", tolower(v1)))
 }

f1(str1)
#[1] "hellos1_s2_s3_s4"

f2(str1)
#[1] "hellos1_s2_s3_s4"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "hello:s1.s2-s3 s4"
```